# initializing iterator before for loop in Dart

Tags: for-loop, dart

In my for loop I'm getting an 'avoid unnecessary statements', the code works fine but I assume there must be a more efficient way of writing the below.

```
int i = 0;
for (i; i < (list.length - list.indexOf('.')); i++)
     ^
```

I'm getting the alert on the first i in the for loop.
I understand that the alternative is to replace it with `var i = 0`, but I've done it this way so I can use the ith position for running the next loop after this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put anything in the first part of the `for`:

```dart
var i = 0;
for (; i < list.length - list.indexOf('.'); i++) ...
```

Putting an `i` there is technically valid, but kindof useless since it doesn't do anything, (which is why you get a warning).

You can also do:

```dart
var i = 0;
for (var n = list.length - list.indexOf('.'); i < n; i++) ...
```

and avoid computing the end for every step of the loop. *That* would be quite a lot more efficient.

You can also do:

```dart
var n = list.length - list.indexOf('.');
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) ...
```

and then use `n` afterwards instead of `i`. That would make it a more traditional loop for readers looking at it.

Comment: Is there a reason var is used as the iterator rather than an int?

Comment: Just following the style guide: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-type-annotating-initialized-local-variables
Dart has type inference, so a variable initialized to zero will have type `int` whether you write it or not,